# Truth set with two variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I have no idea how to go about this question; it asks for the truth set of the following:

$x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $5 \in \{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2 + y^2 < 50 \}$

Can anyone enlighten me on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, $\{x\in\Bbb R|x^2+5^2<50\}=(-5,\,5)$.